# ExpandableListView does not wrap for larger textsizes

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

Why is that when i set a textsize the list items get overlap? Check the images below. This was taken from a sample and by default when we dont set a textsize for the headers the lists shows properly without overlapping one another. After i set a textsize it goes all crazy as highlighted in the after image. Please help me out as ive been trying this for a week.

Before
[image: Before]
After
[image: After]

here are the layout files:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <ExpandableListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:text="@string/main_no_items"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

group_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:textSize="16dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:paddingLeft="50px"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

group2_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:textSize="16px"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:paddingLeft="90dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

child3_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="100px"
         android:textSize="16px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="250px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
         android:textSize="16px"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="150px"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child layout its wrong

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding = "10dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/childname"
         android:paddingLeft="100dp"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/rgb"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try to use dp instead px